# TableBinding.setFormatsAsync throws error in mac desktop excel when 'row' is not mentioned for cell range

Tags: office365, office-js, excel-addins

We have built a Excel Task Pane add-in that works with JavaScript API for Office. We have some code that executes TableBinding.setFormatsAsync(cellFormat, callback). This call throws error which reads

> The row index value is out of the allowed range. Use a value (0 or higher) that's less than the number of rows

when we give the cellRange object as {column: i}, which according to the doc (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.tablebinding.setformatsasync) should specify the range that extends to ith column of data in the table

Sample cellFormat given:

```
               [{
                    cells: {
                        column: 3
                    },
                    format: {
                        fontStyle: "italic",
                        fontColor: "gray"
                    }
                }]
```

Please note that this happens **only on MAC desktop excel**

Comment: Manoj, I am following up on the bug.  In terms of getting you unblocked: is it a requirement for you to use the "Office 2013" style of APIs (`setFormasAsync`)?  Or would you be able to use the Office 2016+ APIs instead, which provide much greater flexibility, and do work identically across desktop/mac/online/ios?

Comment: Thanks for the response @MichaelZlatkovsky . We actually have developed two excel task pane apps. The latest one uses office 2016 apis. The old one was developed before office 2016 apis were available and it uses office 2013 apis. We are planning to migrate to use new apis but that can take few months for us to do so. So, meanwhile we need this to support the old app.